# Error al obtener URL acortada utilizando la API de tinyurl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web

estoy tratando de hacer un acortador de url usando TinyUrl. 
El problema es que me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> System.Net.WebException: 'Error en el servidor remoto: (400) Solicitud
>   incorrecta.'

Ya he intentado leyendo en casi todo el foro pero no he dado con la solución.

El código del controlador es:

```
namespace Prueba.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class TinyURLAPIController : Controller
    {
        // GET: TinyURLAPI
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MakeTinyUrl(string strURL)
        {
            var tinyUrl = WebRequest.Create("la api de tiny=" + strURL);
            var shortUrl = tinyUrl.GetResponse();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(shortUrl.GetResponseStream())){
                ViewData["tinyUrl"] = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return PartialView("Index");

        }
    }
}
```

Y este es el código del Index:

```
<Html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <@Ajax.BeginForm("MakeTinyUrl", new AjaxOptions  { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "tinyUrl" }))>
        @Html.TextBox("url")
        <input id="btnMakeUrl" type="submit" value="Make tinyUrl" onclick="Index" />



</body>
</Html>
```

¿Alguna solución posible?

Comment: No veo el error, soy daltónico. ¿Por qué no transcribes el error en la pregunta en lugar de poner una captura de pantalla?

Comment: Mil disculpas, se me pasó por alto agregar el error fuera de la captura. Ahí lo puse, gracias por notarlo @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: si ingresas en el browser esa url de tinyurl + url que quieres reducir, obtienes una respuesta?

Comment: Sí, si ingreso esa url de tinyurl + url obtengo un link reducido @LeandroTuttini

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene la variable strURL al momento del error?

Comment: Ingreso una url en el campo de texto del index @CarlosPozos

Comment: leo que comentaste que el url debes ingresarla en un textbox de la pagina de tinyurl, si es asi entonces no esta tomando la url que le indicas como parametro, cuando operas desde el browser aplica directo sobre la url que pones como parametro o la que ingresas luego en un textbox ?

Comment: Es la que pongo luego en un textbox @LeandroTuttini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podria ser que el url de la API de tinyurl  no sea correcto.

Tienes esto:

```
var tinyUrl = WebRequest.Create("la api de tiny=" + strURL);
```

Debe ir esto...

```
var tinyUrl = WebRequest.Create("h t t p : /  /t i n y u r l . c o m /api-create.php?url=" + strURL);
```

(puse espacios para que acepte el url)...

Sin embargo, por tu comentario, veo que no es así; por lo tanto, el otro punto que se debe revisar es que el contenido de tu variable strURL sea un url válido. Hice algunas pruebas y por ejemplo, con los siguientes valores obtengo diferentes resultados:

- http://www.stackoverflow.com => .../63tmyk
- www.stackoverflow.com => .../63tmyk
- coffee => [System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
- http://coffee => .../n0rr
- (Cadena vacía) => [System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
- (null) => [System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]

Por lo tanto, tendrías que agregar un error handler para interceptar y responder correctamente en esa situación...

```
namespace Prueba.Controllers
{
   [HandleError]
   public class TinyURLAPIController : Controller
   {
       // GET: TinyURLAPI
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
           return View("Index");
       }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MakeTinyUrl(string strURL)
    {
        try{
           var tinyUrl = WebRequest.Create("la api de tiny=" + strURL);
           var shortUrl = tinyUrl.GetResponse();

           using (var reader = new StreamReader(shortUrl.GetResponseStream())){
               ViewData["tinyUrl"] = reader.ReadToEnd();
           }
        }
        catch(WebException ex){
              ViewData["tinyUrl"] = "Error, el url no es válido"; //Lo puse acá como ejemplo, probablemente debes regresarlo en otra entrada de ViewData
        }
        return PartialView("Index");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: En realidad tengo puesto lo que tú pusiste, solo que como no acepta el url aquí puse "la api de tiny"

Comment: Cierto, asumí mal. Entonces lo que queda es que el contenido de strURL no es correcto. Hice algunas pruebas y el error que mencionas lo regresa cuando el valor de strURL no es un url válido...

Comment: Gracias, era debido al Try/Catch el error. Me ha servido, ¿Para mostrar esa url corta en un label, tienes idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo agregando un control en la view y colocando en su value el contenido que regresas en ViewData, algo así como lo siguiente:                 @Html.TextBox("txtUrl", ViewData["tinyUrl"])

Comment: Hmm, pues no. No me ha funcionado pero gracias, ya veré como arreglar ese detalle

Answer (score 2):

Otra manera de hacerlo sería usando [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Net.Http.HttpClient.%2523ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) junto con su método [`GetStringAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetStringAsync_System_Uri_)

```
/// <summary>
/// Método simple para usar la api de TinyUrl
/// </summary>
/// <param name="baseUrl">Url para utilizar tinyurl</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static async Task<string> TinyUrl(string baseUrl)
{
    //Usamos un HttpClient con la url base de TinyUrl
        using (var api = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://tinyurl.com/") })
    {
        //Devolvemos la respuesta, pasándo de parámetro la url que recibimos..
        return await api.GetStringAsync($"api-create.php?url={baseUrl}");
    }
}
```

Luego simplemente llamas a la función..

```
var result = TinyUrl("google.com").Result;
```

La variable `result` tendrá el link de TinyUrl que se generó.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no le estás pasando una URL válida a la API, por esa razón te retorna un error.

Ve a la siguiente dirección y verás lo que sucede:

`...url=`

En cambio, si vas a la siguiente ya no te regresará error:

`...url=https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/web/devops`

(No me deja colocar la ruta completa, pero en los `...` va la api de tiny)

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Comment: La verdad es que es coo dices, funciona así pero necesito introducir esa url dentro del html en un textbox y que al hacer click en el boton se acorte la url

Comment: Tendrás que validar que la url sea válida, y en caso contrario informar que la url no es válida. ¿Cómo? Con un try - catch